# How to add script to package.json after installing custom npm package

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts, npm-package

I develop **my own npm** package. I want a script to appear in **package.json** after installing my npm package to any node project. I need this so that the user can run my package just using `npm run <script>` and package starts working. According to my idea script will launch js-file in package folder that is inside node_modules folder.

For example, after installing jest package the following script appears: `"test" : "jest"` . How can I do this?

I heard about prepare script but I am not sure that i can use script to add another script.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I haven't seen someone doing this but if you are working on local projects and you want to add your script automatically, you can do the following:
in the npm doc you  can find the lifcyple of each property:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-operation-order

first, you need to add `prepare` to your package script like:

```js
 "scripts": {
    "prepare": "node scripts/postinstall.js"
  }
```

in `postinstall.js` you can read the package.json and add your custom script like:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const scriptName = '<YOUR SCRIPT NAME>'
const scriptCommand = 'node node_modules/<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>/scripts/<YOUR SCRIPT NAME>.js'

const packageJsonPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'package.json')
const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageJsonPath))

packageJson.scripts[scriptName] = scriptCommand

fs.writeFileSync(packageJsonPath, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2))
```

don't forget to replace the names based on your own project names.

hope that helps you solving your problem.

Comment: This way only adds script to installed package, not to main project.

Comment: you can change the path to point it to your root package json